# Private Message System [Inbox Query]

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called "message" and I want to show all talk between users (last message)

Table structure:

```
message_id | user_id | recipient_id | message | status | date
```

Example rows:

```
1 | 1 | 2 | Hello | 0 | 2016-03-26 12:00:00
2 | 2 | 1 | Hi | 0 | 2016-03-26 12:05:00
3 | 1 | 3 | Are you there? I want meet you! :P | 0 | 2016-03-26 12:20:00
4 | 1 | 2 | How are you? | 0 | 2016-03-26 12:10:00
5 | 2 | 1 | Fine :) | 0 | 2016-03-26 12:15:00
6 | 5 | 1 | Hi :D | 0 | 2016-03-26 15:00:00
```

So, result should be (for user_id == 1):

```
3 | 1 | 3 | Are you there? I want meet you! :P | 0 | 2016-03-26 12:20:00
5 | 2 | 1 | Fine :) | 0 | 2016-03-26 12:15:00
6 | 5 | 1 | Hi :D | 0 | 2016-03-26 15:00:00
```

Comment: So you just put in session, id of user and then when they enter "inbox" or something like that show every unique user id, and then if they enter chat with specific user you show all messages between that user and recipient, ordered by date?

Comment: Please read my question one more time, because probably you dont understand.

Comment: Facebook messanger is good example :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you sort by `date`, then you group by `user_id`

```
    SELECT *
      FROM
         (
                SELECT * from messages
                 WHERE `user_id`=1 or `recipient_id`=1
              ORDER BY `date` DESC
         ) m
  GROUP BY `user_id`
```

Result:

```
3 | 1 | 3 | Are you there? I want meet you! :P | 0 | 2016-03-26 12:20:00
5 | 2 | 1 | Fine :)                            | 0 | 2016-03-26 12:15:00
6 | 5 | 1 | Hi :D                              | 0 | 2016-03-26 15:00:00
```

<kbd>**[sqlFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d4aedb/13)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

I hope I will explain better than in my comment, here it goes:

**First**, you need to have logging system, so when user logins you save his ID to session.

**Second**, based on user that is logged you show all messages in "inbox" that he has with other users,select * from message where user_id = $_SESSION['id'], you can join tables and show it names from user and recipient

**Third** when he clicks on some chat with other person then you show all messages between them ordered by date based on user id and recipient_id

Comment: No, because it show only message sent by logged user. 
Messanger is good example of my problem: http://i.imgur.com/9mC1LN1.png

Comment: well it will show to me only messages when I am logged in, where I talked to someone, you get that ? that is the point of "Private" messaging system

Comment: Step 1: user login to website 
Step 2: user go to inbox
Step 3: user see all conversation with other user (login and last message)

Comment: Same as it looks in messenger (facebook)

Comment: And that is what I explained, the last step is when he enters conversation you get id of logged user and of other user in conversation and then sort it by date and you will see all messages, is that what you wanted?

Comment: I want get this same like on messanger

Comment: Do you know PHP ? you have the logic you just have to code it, why don't you check some tutorials on how to make messaging system with PHP and when you have a problem with your code, then you come here

Comment: I have problem with group it, and show only one record between two users: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/58833/14

Answer (score 0):

Would a query like `select * from messages group by user_id order by date` sort you? [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/58833/4) demo.

Comment: Please look for my example (results)